# remove duplicates from two arrays javascript

Tags: javascript

I have two arrays in javascript ,And I wand to remove duplicates from them

```
var array1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
var array2 = [3,5,7,11,17,19];
```

I want the output to be [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,11,17,19]

Comment: `console.log("[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,11,17,19]");`

Answer (score 3):

```
var array1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], array2 = [3,5,7,11,17,19];
var output = array1.concat(array2);
var output = output.filter(function (item, pos) {return output.indexOf(item) == pos});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/1v0sqz5w/)